# How do I read enough data to deserialize a seed of type Int without assuming a fixed number of bits?

Tags: haskell, random, ghc

We are given that [`mkStdGen`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html#v:mkStdGen) has type [`Int`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Int.html#t:Int) → [`StdGen`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html#t:StdGen) and `Int` is defined as

> A fixed-precision integer type with at least the range `[-2^29 .. 2^29-1]`. The exact range for a given implementation can be determined by using [`minBound`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:minBound) and [`maxBound`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:maxBound) from the [`Bounded`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#t:Bounded) class.

In other words, `Int` does not have a fixed upper limit on its width.

The [Expert Beginner](https://twitter.com/ExpertBeginner1) may think, ‘But GHC uses 31-bit `Int` on my machine — good enough for Simon Peyton Jones should be good enough for anyone!’ and with great self-satisfaction write

```
generator :: IO StdGen
generator = do
  withBinaryFile "/dev/urandom" ReadMode $ \h -> do
    let nbytes = 4
        buf = take nbytes $ repeat (0::Word8)
        toInt ws =
          let [a,b,c,d] = (map fromIntegral ws) :: [Word32] in
            fromIntegral $ (shiftL (clearBit a 7) 24) .|.
                           (shiftL           b    16) .|.
                           (shiftL           c     8) .|. d
    withArray buf $ \p -> do
      nread <- hGetBuf h p nbytes
      when (nread /= nbytes) $ error "failed read"
      bytes <- peekArray nbytes p
      return $ mkStdGen (toInt bytes)
```

It did not occur to our hero to check a 64-bit GHC:

```
Prelude> maxBound :: Int
9223372036854775807
Prelude> 2^63
9223372036854775808
```

or some other Haskell whose `Int` has the minimum 29 bits.

How do we implement `generator` so as to avoid wasting or overflowing seed bits?

Comment: As you noted, int depends on a number of details. Why not use a generator with an architecture independent operation? One that already provided a serialization format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`FiniteBits`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Bits.html#t:FiniteBits) class has got your back.

```
Data.Bits> finiteBitSize (0 :: Int)
64
```